# How can I manually trigger a ForeSee survey dialog to display with javascript? or URL parameters?

Tags: javascript

I haven't been able to find any API documentation for [ForeSee](http://foreseeresults.com/), and I've had a bug report come in related to the ForeSee Survey prompt dialog that gets randomly displayed. I've tried clearing cache and cookies, but it hasn't displayed for me yet, is there a way to trigger its display with javascript? Or maybe with certain URL parameters?

In `foresee-trigger.js` I've updated the `FSR.sites` array to include a reference to localhost:

```
var FSR = {
    'version': '7.0.0',
    'date': '01/01/2011',
    'enabled': true,
    'auto' : true,
    'encode' : true,
    'files': './foresee/', //default path when no match below         
    'id': 'etc',
    'sites': [
    /* several existing ones, etc.*/
    {
        name: 'localhost',
        path: 'localhost',
        files: '//localhost/subdirectory/foresee/',
        domain: 'localhost'
    },{
        path: '.',
        domain: 'default'
    }]
};
```

Comment: This being the one and only question apparently ever asked about this software/API/whatever, i kinda doubt you're gonna get much help here.  Have you tried asking ForeSee?

Comment: I've reached out to them on twitter and they gave me a list of people to email. I haven't heard back yet. I'm surprised that no one else has run into this since these surveys seem so common, but my googling only returns press releases and ways to block the script from running.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to manually set the sampling percentage for your current session by hitting the "fsradmin.html" page that should be located in the same directory as the foresee-trigger.js file.  For example, localhost/YourApp/scripts/foresee/fsradmin.html.  Setting the sampling percentage to 100% would ensure that you encounter the survey.

Another option is to change the actual sampling percentage in the foresee-surveydef.js file here:

> criteria: {
>
> > ```
> >    sp: 75,  //this is the sampling % - set it to 100 to ensure that it appears
> >    lf: 1  // loyalty factor, (the # of pages the user has to hit before it appears)
> > ```
> >
> > },

If you chose the 2nd option, be sure to set the sampling % back to the original value before deploying your code, or everyone will always get the survey.

Finally here's a link to their documentation: http://demo.foreseeresults.com/_code/docs/ForeSee_Trigger_Code_Implementation_Guide.pdf

Comment: I've got all the sp values cranked up to 100 but I'm still not seeing them. I'll double-check my cookies...

Comment: Thanks for posting a link to the implementation guide. I could not find any reference to it on the Foresee website.

Comment: +1, having never used this and inheriting an app with it, this saved me tons of time looking through that minified trigger file.

Answer (score 2):

FSR.showInvite();
It will only display if Foresee isn't displayed yet to the user, means cookie isn't created yet.
If you want to verify then first clear the cache. Load the page where foresee code is written and in developer console trigger the above command. It would show the survey dialog.